# In wso2 api manager why tables of WSO2CARBON_DB and SHARED_DB are the same with diffrent config?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

As mentioned in the [reference](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-oracle/) WSO2CARBON_DB and SHARED_DB, db-scripts are same, so why there two separate config for them in `deployment.toml`?:

I configured them in oracle, but there are same tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, the `CARBON_DB` is used to store meta-information related to the node itself, and it is not recommended to share the `CARBON_DB` across nodes. Whereas the `SHARED_DB` contains both, Registry related information and user and roles-related information. You can learn more about the Databases [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/overview/). Both `CARBON_DB` and `SHARED_DB` use the same set of tables, but when it comes to a functional point of view, the data and entries stored in both are different (`CARBON` focuses on storing the node's information, whereas the `SHARED` is to store other registry and user artifacts).

If you are having a distributed setup, the `CARBON_DB` needs to be configured separately for each node and will not be shared among. Therefore, you can either go with an RDBMS or the default H2 for the `CARBON_DB`. However, the `SHARED_DB` needs to be configured and shared across the nodes to share the data-related users and roles. Further, the `SHARED_DB` also holds a set of data related to APIs and registries. These are needed by both Publisher and Devportal nodes (specifically) to index and list all the APIs in the Portals.

Hope this gives you a brief understanding of the differences between each database.